# Client Object Model - Select distinct

Tags: 2010, development, client-object-model

I am using ClientObjectModel (C#) to retreive data from a custom list, which is structured like this:

[image: ListStructure]

What i need is some kind of "select distinct" which retreives only the categories, without duplicates:

```
cat1; cat2; cat3;
```

Im not able to find a way with CAML, and iterating through all items is not an option (the list contains 6000 items, to load each of them is very slow). Is there any other way I dont know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally CAML query even in SharePoint 2013 doesn't have distinct function you can use, however I find this code that can help you,

```
 protected void btn_binddropdown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SPList oList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["CAMLTEST"];
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Name' /></OrderBy>";
                DataTable dtcamltest = oList.GetItems(query).GetDataTable();
                DataView dtview = new DataView(dtcamltest);
                DataTable dtdistinct = dtview.ToTable(true, "Name");
                ddl_names.DataSource = dtdistinct; 
                ddl_names.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddl_names.DataValueField = "Name";
                ddl_names.DataBind();                           



            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                Response.Write("Exception at btn_binddropdown_Click :" + exe);
            }
       }
```

[image]

[Source](http://camlq.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/how-to-get-distinct-unique-values-from.html)

If nothing works then you still have choice of Custom web services or use jQuery or JS to select distinct list items,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560550/what-is-the-best-way-to-retrieve-distinct-unique-values-using-spquery

[Possible to get distinct values from GetListItems?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11666/possible-to-get-distinct-values-from-getlistitems)

[How to retrieve distinct values with JavaScript Client Object Model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27212/how-to-retrieve-distinct-values-with-javascript-client-object-model)